# Ionic 1 app on iOS, when multiple apps open it is using/absorbing first apps pages

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, debugging, ionic-framework

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Please see attached video from google drive. (was too large to upload as a gif)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R_DFPwehqHiLL6AnV-9-gvj5njV_2UiH/view?usp=sharing

The apps being opened are all our apps downloaded from the app store. When opening one after the other and having them run in the background, they are absorbing the first opened app's page. (as seen in the video).

E.g. Spur app gets opened, then johndorys app opens and has Spur app's login page, then panarottis opens and also has Spur's login page.

Only happening with iOS.

All apps are using Ionic 1 and are built from the same code base (so have the same file names etc) but each theme has it's own styles, databases, id's etc.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encountered this same issue it was due to the cordova plugin:
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

Details about issue and fixes can be found here:
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/165